# On subpage I want a new routing system using Angular-UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Trying UI-Router - this is not a SPA - but multiple pages with collection of SPA built in as subpages

I want a user to navigate to the user to `http://domain/comp`. This is a subpage with essentially its own states.

This link will be used in marketing so I do not want to have any `#!` or use html5 mode.

When the user lands on this page it should reflect the initial state

```
http://domain/comp/#!/form
```

But this is what it's not initiating, I utilise

```
$urlRouterProvider.when "/comp", "form"
```

To try and URL match - but this I believe wants to match on

```
/comp/#!/comp and then start the state form
```

I do not want to use the catchall

```
$urlRouterProvider.when "", "form"
```

As I essentially bundle all my JS into one so don't have the separation for bundles on each page

Basically is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: Gonna try $urlRouterProvider + stateProvider to see if this will work

Comment: In the end I created a ng-app and a new module per internal SPA - basically the MPA with SPA within needed a bit more thoughtful configuration.